# componentWillReceiveProps not called despite returning new state object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have the following mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  surveysRequest: () => dispatch(DashboardActions.surveysRequest()),
  surveysFilter: () => dispatch(DashboardActions.surveysFilter())
});
```

and in my `componentDidMount` I'm calling the method

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.animation) {
    this.animation.play();
  }

  this.props.surveysRequest()
}
```

The `surveysSuccess` reducer does get called, an even though I am returning a new state, `componentWillReceiveProps` is never called

```
const surveysSuccess = createAsyncSuccess(ASYNC_GET, (state, action) => {
    return state.merge({
      surveys: action.data
    })
  }
)
```

Using the latest ignite react native boilerplate https://github.com/infinitered/ignite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/componentdidmakesense-react-lifecycle-explanation-393dcb19e459

`componentWillReceiveProps` is only called when the props that the component receives changes. If the state changes, `componentWillReceiveProps` will not be called. Try using `componentWillUpdate` or `componentShouldUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making shallow copy of your state object and  nested values are still being  passed by reference.

[`From docs here`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

> **mapStateToProps** function will also be re-invoked whenever the connected component receives new props as determined by shallow equality comparisons.

Solution :

```
const surveysSuccess = createAsyncSuccess(ASYNC_GET, (state, action) => {

    let newState= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)); //add it before using state.
     //rest code
})
```